# Check if none of list elements contain searched substring

Tags: python, list, substring

I have list:

```
myList = ['qwer', 'tyu', 'iop12', '3456789']
```

How to check if none of elements in list contains searched substring,

- for string `'wer'` result should be False (exist element containing substring)
- for string `'123'` result should be True (none of element contain such substring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
not any(search in s for s in myList)
```

Or alternatively:

```
all(search not in s for s in myList)
```

For example:

```
>>> myList = ['qwer', 'tyu', 'iop12', '3456789']
>>> not any('wer' in s for s in myList)
False
>>> not any('123' in s for s in myList)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `any` and `all` functions are very useful.

```
not any(substring in element for element in myList)
```

Test runs show that

```
>>> myList = ['qwer', 'tyu', 'iop12', '3456789']
>>> substring = 'wer'
>>> not any(substring in element for element in myList)
False
>>> substring = '123'
>>> not any(substring in element for element in myList)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `any`:

```
>>> myList = ['qwer', 'tyu', 'iop12', '3456789']
>>> not any('wer'  in x for x in myList)
False
>>> not any('123' in x for x in myList)
True
```